# Deployed smart contract on base with REMIX but now it wont show in remix and i cant verify the contract

Tags: remix-tests

here is the contract im trying to verify. it seems i lost the original code from REMIX.

https://library.dedaub.com/base/address/0xf518a23ec64feec4869860eafb4d7d717a987e9d